# Blocking a contact in Windows Live Messenger 2011

Tags: contacts, windows-live-messenger, blocking

Is it possible to block a contact in the new version of Windows Live Messenger? I am not seeing the option anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feature has been removed. Right click the contact and then use "Appear offline to this person".

[image]

Image from http://www.computertipsfree.com/how-to-block-contact-in-windows-live-messenger-2011/

Comment: such nice red lines! how do you create them?

Comment: @studiohack [Techsmith's Snagit](http://www.techsmith.com/snagit/) is what I always use. But this image wasn't taken by me since I only have Live messenger in Dutch.